# Get Output of Copy Activity present Inside the Switch in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Copy Activity Inside a switch Activity. I need to pass the rowsWritten to a notebook present outside the switch activity.

How Will I be available to pass the output of copy activity to the notebook present outside the switch activity.

I have already used Pipeline Variables to achieve this. Exploring for an alternate solution without the use of Pipeline variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***AFAIK***, We cannot get the activity outputs which are inside Switch in the outside of it by referencing it.

As the ADF and we don’t know which case will be executed inside Switch, that’s why when we reference those outside it will say `The output of activity 'Lookup1' can't be referenced since it is either not an ancestor to the current activity or does not exist`.

Here I have used two lookups inside two Switch cases and when I get the output of one Lookuo activity outside Switch, you can see the error.

[image]

Also, it will fail on Validation of the pipeline.

[image]

As you said, **Using a Pipeline variable and set variable activities inside every case and storing the activity output(rowsWritten) and using that variable outside Switch activity** is the workaround for it.