# Azure Data Factory: Accessing a variable value set inside a Switch activity outside of the Switch in the same pipeline

Tags: azure, switch-statement, azure-data-factory

There is already an answer to possibly the same thing here:
[Get Output of Copy Activity present Inside the Switch in Azure Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74889444/get-output-of-copy-activity-present-inside-the-switch-in-azure-data-factory)

But how exactly does this work: "Using a Pipeline variable and set variable activities inside every case and storing the activity output(rowsWritten) and using that variable outside Switch activity"?

I have tried to do this so that the Switch activity and the Set variable activity trying to use the activity output from the Switch are in the same pipeline. Can this even work?

This should give an idea on what I'm trying to do:
[image]
[image]
This is how I'm setting the Pipeline return value inside one case of the Switch:
[image]
This is how I'm trying to use a value retrieved from the Switch in a Set variable activity in the same pipeline:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried to do this so that the Switch activity and the Set variable activity trying to use the activity output from the Switch are in the same pipeline. Can this even work?

No, this won't work. I tried the same and got below error when trying to access Switch activity return value.

[image]

Here, A pipeline return value will be used when we are calling this pipeline(Child pipeline) from another pipeline. This can only be accessed from its parent pipeline(Using Execute pipeline activity) and Switch activity won't give the return value inside Switch.

[image]

> But how exactly does this work: "Using a Pipeline variable and set variable activities inside every case and storing the activity output(rowsWritten) and using that variable outside Switch activity"?

Go through the below demo to understand about it.

First create a variable of required type in the pipelines variables list.

[image]

**Inside every Switch activity case**, store the lookup activity output value in this same variable(`count_var`) using set variable activity like below.

You need to do the same for the **default case of the switch as well**. Store any value in this same variable `count_var` as per your requirement for the default case.

[image]

As you want to use this value inside Foreach, in every iteration, **this set variable activity in each switch case will update the value according the Switch case**.

In each iteration, you can use the same variable `variables("count_var")` to do your operations.

For sample, here I am doing a subtraction and storing the value in another variable.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Ah, thanks! I had first tried with pipeline variable, but failed probably because I didn't fill in the default case at all.